# C#　起動中のExcelに書き込みする際の動作が不安定（Interop,Excel2010)

Tags: c#, excel

どなたかご存知の方お教えいただきたいです。
現在開発中の機能で、「起動中のExcelにDBから取得した値を転記する」
という機能があります。
問題なく書き込みできる場合もあるのですが、どうも動作が不安定で、
転記できる場合とできない場合があります。

この機能を使用する業務は緊急を要する場合が多いので、
不安定さは解消する必要があり、困っています。
環境はWindows7Professioal、Excel2010　C#　Visualstudio2012です。

起動時のメソッドは以下を使用しています。
Marshal.GetActiveObject( "Excel.Application" )

Comment: できない場合はどのような挙動になりますか？（エラーが出る、開発中のアプリないしExcelが固まる、ただ何も起きない、など）

Comment: Excelがファイルを自動保存する設定(自動バックアップ)になっていませんか？　ファイルを保存している最中のExcelは、他のシステムからのアクセスに反応しなかったりしますけど。

Comment: できない場合の挙動は、「何もおきない」です。

Comment: ファイル保存についても確認してみます。

Comment: 解決策が見つかったようで何よりですが、このままでは解決済みであることが他の方に伝わりにくいですし、ご自身でそれを回答として投稿していただけませんか？その上で（質問投稿から2日待たなければいけませんが）投稿した回答のチェックマークをクリックすると、その回答で解決したというマークになりますので、できればこちらもお願いします。

Comment: 初投稿でしたので、作法がわからず申し訳ございません。回答記載しましたので、また解決済みにもしておきます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

ご質問の内容だけではわからないのですが、リリース漏れ問題の可能性も考えられると思いました。

COMオブジェクトはリファレンスカウンター方式のためリリース漏れがあるとそれ以降の動作が不安定になります。

リリース漏れ後は目に見えないExcelアプリケーションインスタンス(以下EAIと略)が残ってしまうので、見かけ上起動中のEAIが一つに見えても実際は複数存在している状態になります。この状態ではGetActiveObjectがどのEAIを返すかは保証されませんのでEAIへの操作結果が画面を持つExcel上に反映されたりされなかったりといったことが起こると思います。

Comment: なるほど。勉強になります。リリース漏れの可能性についても調査してみます。

Answer (score 0):

原因発覚し、解決しました。
複数のexcelを起動していた時の動作が問題でした。
GetActiveObjectでは起動しているExcelが1つのみの場合のみ有効ということでした。

http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/4634
上記URLを参考に、ROTから検索することで、解決できました。
お忙しい中ご回答いただきました皆様、ありがとうございました。